# Guzzle GET with APIKey and APITokern

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

Good Evening Everyone.

Have been searching for a week to try and find a way of connecting using guzzle.

```
curl -v https://go.paytraq.com/api/{APICall}?APIToken={APIToken}&APIKey={APIKey} \ 
-H "Content-Type:text/xml" \ 
-d "{RequestBody}"
```

I tried all methods and keep getting unauthorised access and not sure the best way to pass APIToken and APIKey.

I have used the above from terminal and it works fine.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri'=>'https://go.paytraq.com']);

  $request = $client->request('GET','/api/clients',['debug'=>true],[ 'headers'=>
  'APIToken=XXXXXX&APIKey=XXXX'
  ]);
```

The above is the last version of my code which gives me the below error

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Client error: `GET https://go.paytraq.com/api/clients` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: API key or token is not provided

And below is the guzzle debug

```
 Trying 52.16.7.7:443... * Connected to go.paytraq.com (52.16.7.7) port 443 (#0) * ALPN, offering http/1.1 * successfully set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 * ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol * Server certificate: * subject: CN=go.paytraq.com * start date: Oct 14 00:00:00 2019 GMT * expire date: Nov 14 12:00:00 2020 GMT * subjectAltName: host "go.paytraq.com" matched cert's "go.paytraq.com" * issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon * SSL certificate verify ok. > GET /api/clients HTTP/1.1 Host: go.paytraq.com User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/7 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 < Date: Sat, 01 Aug 2020 21:03:49 GMT < Request-Time: 1 < Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) < Content-Length: 32 < Connection: keep-alive < * Connection #0 to host go.paytraq.com left intact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$client->request('GET', '/api/clients', ['query' => [
      'APIToken' => $APIToken,
      'APIKey' => $APIkey]
]);
```